# Variable in C with limited range of acceptable values

Tags: c, variables, range

How can I have a variable in C whose value should lie only between 20 to 520? I want to restrict that variable assignment to values between 20 to 520?
In case I take an enum whose value shall start from 20, I still need to define another 519 values inside enum.

Comment: You can't short of modeling this with something "private" and writing your own accessor functions.

Comment: @AndriyBerestovskyy what "don't you think"?

Comment: C language hasn't this feature!

Comment: And what should happen when an illegal assignment happening?

Comment: Maybe using C++ you might write a class able to manage this problem!

Comment: You can't do this in C. In C++ it's possible.

Comment: @Jabberwocky how would I do it in c++?

Answer (score 9):

C doesn't have a way to *directly* express what you want. Note that even an `enum` doesn't **enforce** valid values. You can assign *any* value of the underlying type of an `enum`.

You could always come up with your own logic, e.g. if this is part of an object you model as a struct:

```
struct foo
{
    unsigned bar;
};

// [...]

int foo_setBar(struct foo *self, unsigned val)
{
    if (val < 20 || val > 520) return -1;
    self->bar = val;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A `typedef unsigned int foo` would save the `->` or `.` operator wouldn't it?

Comment: Huh? That would typedef `foobar` as an alias to `int` ... what do you mean?

Comment: Instead of using a structure why not using a typedef...?

Comment: Because a) a struct is what you will probably have in a non-trivial program and b) it allows you to use an opaque pointer to *really* enforce usage of your custom accessor.

Answer (score 5):

> How can I have a variable in C whose value should lie only between 20 to 520 ?

*There is not such a data type in C.*

Even if the range was something close to the limits of some types, the danger of underflowing or overflowing would be still be a thing (imagine an `unsigned int` for example, where you want the lower bound to be 0, but someone can excess that bound).

---

What you *can* do though is to write your own structures, accessors and/or enum(s) to achieve that. If you are interested read Paul R's answer. However I don't encourage you to do so.

I would do this, if for example the variable was to be filled by the user:

```
int v;
do {
    scanf("%d", &v);
} while(!(v >= 20 && v <= 520));
```

so that the user will be prompted again and again, until his input match the criteria.

---

PS: This sounds like an XY question.

Comment: Of course you can. You can simply use opaque structures and accessors. It's a terrible solution, but it is possible.

Comment: @kay well.. to an extent. You can't force the compiler to typecheck it for you.

Comment: kay I meant to say what @EugeneSh. said.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, C does not provide access control to struct members. So bad luck at first.

You have to (try to?) work around this limitation in any suitable way. One could be hiding away the data from the user:

type.h:

```
#include <stdbool.h>

struct TheType;
typedef struct TheType TheType;

unsigned short get(TheType const* type);
bool set(TheType* type, unsigned short value);
```

type.c:

```
struct TheType
{
    unsigned short value;
}

unsigned short get(TheType const* type)
{
    return type->value;
}

bool set(TheType* type, unsigned short value)
{
    if(value < 20 || value > 520)
        return false;
    type->value = value;
    return true;
}
```

This comes with another drawback, though, as other features such as `sizeof` get unusable, too... We'd probably have to provide at least a function `size_t sizeofTheType()` allowing the user to allocate appropriate amount of memory and possibly other stuff, too.

Answer (score 2):

Well you sort of can:

```
typedef enum {
    F_FIRST = 20,
    E_LAST = 520
} MySpecialEnum;
```

However this range will not be enforced, either at compile-time or at run-time, but you can use it for explicit range-checking, and as an aid to self-documenting code.

---

Remember this is C, a low level language. If you want run-time checking of variables with user-defined ranges then consider a language such as Pascal, where you can declare a *subrange* variable like this:

```pascal
PROGRAM test;

VAR
  x : 20 .. 520;

BEGIN
  x := 20;   // OK
  x := 1000; // error
END.
```

and then you get range-checking at run-time without any explicit code. Of course there is a performance penalty of this.

Comment: But with this I can't assign value in between 20 and 520, right ?

Comment: There is no such option in C directly. You need if statements to check values. Direct option does not exists.

Comment: `MySpecialEnum foo = -1;` (not my downvote, but maybe for this ... enum doesn't enforce anything) -- I see you edited it in :)

Comment: How is that different from checking the integer range directly? It only obfuscates the code. Also enum constants are `int` only.

Comment: @Olaf: I thought I'd explained its limitations and usefulness in the answer?

Answer (score 1):

It may be possible in C++. But as far as using C syntax, it's impossible. So you will have to use ugly DSL like below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define DEFINE_VAR(x) int ____________________ ## x = 0;

#define VARIDATE_VAR(x) \
  assert(20 <= ____________________ ## x && ____________________ ## x <= 520);

#define SET_VAR(x, y) { \
  ____________________ ## x = y; \
  VARIDATE_VAR(x) \
  }

#define GET_VAR(x) ____________________ ## x


int
main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  DEFINE_VAR(n);
  SET_VAR(n, 30);
  return 0;
}
```